# An argument in proof of Theorem that a set Y has a System of Distinct Representatives iff Marriage Condition holds

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am self studying introductory combinatorics from Richard Brualdi and I am unable to think about the theor on Page 327 of Fifth edition of the book.

Added Image of the theorem[image]

[image]

I have doubt in image 2 in room to spare case.

> My question -> In 5th line of room to spare case author writes Each set of family A contains atleast 1 element ( which is clear) but why at least two elements must be there in each set.

Can someone please explain why it must be true?

I shall be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select $A_i\in\mathcal{A}$.  The claim in doubt is that $|A_i|\geq 2$.  Indeed, since $\{A_i\}$ is a subfamily of $\mathcal{A}$ of size $k=1$ members, its union contains at least $k+1=2$ elements.  But the union is just $A_i$ itself.